# How to insert html content on a page in Observer?

Tags: event-observer

How to insert html content before the `</body>` tag, via Event and Observer on each page?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use layout configuration instead of Event Observer to insert HTML content before the `</body>` tag.

To achieve that,

1. Add `default.xml` to your custom theme or your custom module based on your need.

- If you want to add it to your custom **module**, the path should be `app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`
- If you want to add it to your custom **theme**, the path should be `app/code/YourThemeVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block name="custom_content_before_body_end" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom_content_before_body_end.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. Add `custom_content_before_body_end.phtml` to your custom theme or your custom module based on your need.

- If you want to add it to your custom **module**, the path should be `app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/templates/html/custom_content_before_body_end.phtml`
- If you want to add it to your custom **theme**, the path should be `app/code/YourThemeVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/custom_content_before_body_end.phtml`

Content:

```
Your custom content goes here
```